# Use custom class in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In app/Library I have a file called `Helpers.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Library\Helpers;

class Helpers {
  public function truncate($text) {
    if (strlen($text) > 200) {
      preg_replace('/\s+?(\S+)?$/', '', substr($text, 0, 201));
    }
    return $text;
  }
}
```

In one of my views, I want to use the class:

```
  @foreach($data['articles'] as $article)
    <div class="container">
      <div class="article">
        <h1>{{ $article->title }}</h1>
        <p>
          <?php
            $helpers = new \App\Library\Helpers;
            echo $helpers->truncate($article->body);
          ?>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  @endforeach
```

I get this error:

`Class 'App\Library\Helpers' not found`

Comment: why you not use this function in constants files ?

Comment: @DsRaj What's constant files?

Comment: you can define function or variable in constants file create file in config folder config/constants.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use a namespace not a class, your class is actually `App\Library\Helpers\Helpers`. Using blade you can use the [inject](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/blade#service-injection) method to get your class in a view.

```
@inject('helpers', 'App\Library\Helpers\Helpers')

@foreach($data['articles'] as $article)
    <div class="container">
        <div class="article">
            <h1>{{ $article->title }}</h1>
            <p>{{ $helpers->truncate($article->body) }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Using inject creates a new variable of the name passed as the first argument with a value of the class passed in as the second argument. Your helpers are now available in the view.

Comment: I'm getting `Class App\Library\Helpers does not exist`

Comment: Oh I see... I fixed the `namespace` to `App\Library`, then used the inject `App\Library\Helpers`, now it works.

Comment: Glad you got it working. If you wouldn't mind accepting the answer I'd appreciate it. :-)

Comment: Your answer actually didn't seem to work though... I think you should change it to what I did... but I'll accept anyway!

Comment: Hmm... I'm fairly certain it works according your question. If the namespace was incorrect, it wasn't reflected in your question ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
    $helpers = new App\Library\Helpers\Helpers;
    echo $helpers->truncate($article->body);
  ?>
```

Or fix the namespace name.

```
namespace App\Library;
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped me fix the namespace.

Comment: you can add class name laravel aliases on app.php
'Helper' => App\Library\Helpers::class
and easy use
new \Helper;